# hg repo and kbfiles extension

Tags: mercurial, convert

I've used Mercurial repository with [kbfiles](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/how-do-you-use-kbfiles) but now I have to use pure Mercurial. How to convert repo from kbfiles to pure hg? They are not compatible and seem I will lose all history if I not find the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean convert the history back to a repository where the big files that were managed by the kbfiles extension are now stored directly in the history?

If so, then use

```
$ hg kbfconvert --tonormal your-kb-files-repo normal-repo
```

and you'll get a repository that doesn't require kbfiles.